# Can I override the error AutoCAD gives about my older video card?

Tags: macbook-pro

I have a macbook 2,1 upgraded to 4GB ram and 500 GB hard drive. When installing AutoCAD, it complains that i have an older video card. Granted, that is true, I only use autocad for 2d purposes only. Is there a way to override that error?

Comment: I don´t have AutoCAD, but for some software I´ve been successful to edit the installation script inside the Installer.app to not check for certain hardware features (by editing any `is hardware supported?` routine to always return `true`. You will probably want to use  have to right-click the installer and "show package contents" and from there on, you´re basically on your own.

Comment: do you know how to fix the "Whip failed to initialize" error?

Comment: @joao No but I bought a new MBP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Asmus's suggestion I found that if you remove your graphic card's model from the file unspt_gfx_cards you can install AutoCad. So to recap:

1. Copy the .mpkg package out of the DMG file to some place like your Desktop
2. Right click on the package and select 'Show Package Contents'
3. Browse to Contents/Resources/unspt_gfx_cards
4. Right click unspt_gfx_cards and open with textedit
5. Remove all lines that contain Intel or GMA(for your macbook) and save
6. Double click on the .mpkg to install without hardware restrictions

Not sure if you will have any problems running Autocad but at least you should be able to install it.

Comment: Although this solves the installation problem, I still can't run autocad due to "whip" failed to initialize error

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that would work but you still won't be able to use it as it will give a WHIP error.

Solution: Buy a new i5/i7 Mac, or use BootCamp to boot into Windows XP or 7 and run from there.